# Does Google test Framework support JAVA language.? Or does it support only C++? If yes, what is the alternate for Google test Framework for JAVA

Tags: java, googletest

I checked the official Google Test site, it says it supports C++. I want to clarify does it also support JAVA by any chance , if not what alternative can i use to test my JAVA application hosted on Google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most spread testing for Java is **JUnit**, I don't know if hosting on google cloud changes anything of the usage of it.